# Why iPhones at home need Settings->General->Reset->Reset Network Settings for App Store Updates?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, settings

My wife and I both have iPhone-5s'.  They seem to have no problems using the wifi for anything at home, like Airplay, Pandora, and web surfing, etc.  We can do seemingly everything.  However, for some unknown reason, the iPhones won't do updates.  I see the badges showing how many, and the store seems to connect, but updates don't download and install.  It doesn't work to forget the network and rejoin, I need to actually go through the process of Settings->General->Reset->Reset Network Settings and then rejoin in order for the updates to download.  Then everything downloads and installs.  It seems to need this at random time intervals of about every 2-4 weeks.  I would really like to eliminate the need for resetting the network settings.  (It forgets all networks and passwords, which makes it a pain if I go anywhere else with the iPhone).

I have seen this problem with and without White Listing MAC addresses on the Airport Extreme Base Station(s) wifi access.

As additional information, my setup for my home network is as follows.  Cisco RV325g router, with a AEB-802.11ac in the back of the house and an AEB-802.11n in the front of the house.  They are both connected to the Cisco via Ethernet ports, and setup as a roaming network.  (Same Network name and password for the AEB(s) ).
It also does not matter which AEB is being connected to via wifi.

Thank you in advance for your assistance. (Also, if I have posted improperly, or to the incorrect location, I apologize.  This is my first post here, and I am still learning how to get around here).

Best Regards,
KShapiro

Comment: Did you ever think to bring it into an Apple Store? Since this is a recurring problem I would take it into the Apple Store.

Comment: The Updates work on other networks.  Have already been to an Apple Store to check, but they have no idea what is going on.  The best solution they came up with was to continue to reset network settings.  I would like to solve the problem so I don't need to keep needing to reset the network settings and then re-learn the network.